# Iterate through directory filenames using JavaScript on ASP.NET C#

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I'm trying to read all filenames from a specified (server- not client) folder, and insert all the filenames into a javascript `Array`.
It should behave like the `Directory.GetFiles` method in ASP.NET C#.
I created a new array, and I just need the loop method (Javascript or jQuery) to iterate in the specific folder, and insert all the filenames into the array. 
Thanks all helpers!

Comment: You do not have access to the file system in javascript (and that is a Good Thing). You can have the server generate the list of files and emit the list as a javascript array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need to invoke some form of ajax postback to do this on the server, returning an array of strings as a JSON result.

Note that this has the usual caveats that the web server account must have the necessary permissions to be able to query the selected folder.

Comment: Hello Neil and thanks for your answer! Im trying to create a dynamic image gallery in jQuery that reads images filenames from a constant directory and loads them into a js array, but the filenames are dynamic and not constant. Is there any other way that you suggest me to do so ? Thank you very much!

Comment: You will need to write a method in your web app which calls the Directory.GetFiles() method to enumerate your image filenames. This is C# code in a code-behind module. The method returns the resulting string array json-encoded.

Use the jQuery.post() function (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to invoke the method, specifying a datatype of "json". The data that is returned is a javascript version of the string array returned by the method above.

Rick Strahl has a guide on linking asp.net to jQuery via ajax, here: http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/jquery/jquerypart2.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do this - it's potentially a security problem.

Out of interest, why are you doing this? I'm trying to imagine what you gain from having this information on the client...

Comment: Hello Martin, and thanks for your answer.  
The folder that I need to loop in is in the MACHINE SERVER SIDE, and not on the client's side. I guess i didn't mention it clear enough... the folder & files are located in the web application localhost, not on the client's machine. Thanks.